# How to get date/time of the last system hibernate / suspend / resume?

Tags: suspend, hibernate, resume

How to get date/time of these events:

- last system hibernate / suspend
- last system resume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented Byte Commader's response, for some reason atleast on my two Ubuntu 16 installations it seems that "PM: suspend" and "PM: resume" events both are written into syslog during resume. So the suspend time in that solution is within one second same as the resume time. However, the resume time is correct.

So this solution is not based on log files. It is based on very simple service running continuously and monitoring time difference before and after a sleep. If the difference is much bigger than sleep time then there has been a "pause", e.g. suspend/resume operation. Pause is logged after wakeup when the time is synced.

`pauselogger.sh`

```bash
set -e

if [[ "$#" < 1 || "$#" > 1 ]]
then
    echo "Illegal number of parameters"
    echo "Usage $0 <sleeptime in seconds>"
    exit 1
fi

sleepTime=$1
fileName="/var/log/state.log"

dateStr1=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %T.%N %z %s")
dateInt1=$(echo $dateStr1 | cut -d' ' -f4)
dateInt2=$dateInt1
dateStr2=$dateStr1
diff=0
for (( ; ; ))
do
    diff="$(($dateInt1-$dateInt2))"
    maxDiff=$(echo $sleepTime*1.1 + 1 | bc) # Pause is 10% longer than sleep.
    if (( $(echo "$diff > $maxDiff" |bc -l) )); then  
        echo "$dateStr2 DOWN pre sleep" >> $fileName
        echo "$dateStr1 UP post sleep $diff" >> $fileName       
    fi

    dateStr2=$dateStr1
    dateInt2=$dateInt1

    sleep $sleepTime

    dateStr1=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %T.%N %z %s")
    dateInt1=$(echo $dateStr1 | cut -d' ' -f4)

done
```

Service definition is also simple file: /etc/systemd/system/pauselogger.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Simple Pause Logger

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/pauselogger.sh 30
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Logger is then started and enabled:

```
sudo systemctl start pauselogger
sudo systemctl enable pauselogger
```

Log file:

```
2019-09-13 00:44:17.602146211 +0300 1568324657 UP post sleep 225
2019-09-13 01:04:59.968326886 +0300 1568325899 DOWN pre sleep
2019-09-13 10:25:18.575107533 +0300 1568359518 UP post sleep 33619
2019-09-13 10:49:41.594151484 +0300 1568360981 DOWN pre sleep
2019-09-13 10:51:57.129617072 +0300 1568361117 UP post sleep 136
```

**Pros** of this solution is that it works despite the pause command. It records pauses if OS level suspend/hibernate/resume is used, but it also works if used inside a VM, e.g. VirtualBox savestate/resume.

**Cons** are atleast that both log entries are written during wakeup, this solution is not suitable e.g. if a script is needed to be launched just before savestate operation. Also the command causing sleep/wakeup is not recorded: OS suspend vs VirtualBox savestate or OS resume vs VirtualBox start.

Comment: maybe it will help somebody: I've noted I have `suspend entry (deep)` in syslog (`journalctl`) with timestamp of only after resume, but previous entries, e.g. `Starting Suspend` and `Suspending system` were with timestamp of much earlier, apparently before suspend. So one can grep for those.

Answer (score 14):

You could examine your system log file `/var/log/syslog` for messages indicating suspend/hibernate/resume events and look at their timestamps.

For suspend and resume, check e.g. this pattern:

```bsh
grep -E 'PM: suspend (entry|exit)' /var/log/syslog
```

Example output:

```bsh
Sep  8 09:43:26 type40mark3 kernel: [150509.893804] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Sep  8 15:03:39 type40mark3 kernel: [150514.147721] PM: suspend exit
Sep  8 16:33:41 type40mark3 kernel: [155914.275076] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Sep  8 17:04:58 type40mark3 kernel: [155919.343276] PM: suspend exit
```

This only checks the current syslog file, but as it is subject to log rotation, older messages will be archived in numbered and compressed files like `/var/log/syslog.1` and `/var/log/syslog.2.gz`. To check all of these at once, use `zgrep` instead, which can read compressed files, and `sort` to get them back in order by the actual timestamp date:

```bsh
zgrep -hE 'PM: suspend (entry|exit)' /var/log/syslog* | sort -M
```

To get only the last two lines (last suspend and resume, usually), you can append `| tail -n 2` to either of the above commands.

If you want only suspend or only resume, alter the filter pattern to e.g. `PM: suspend entry` or `PM: suspend exit` accordingly.

---

I don't have a hibernating system available right now to search for appropriate messages for that event, but I expect something similar. Try searching e.g. `grep hiber /var/log/syslog` to find a suitable pattern. When you have one, please comment and I'll gladly add it to this answer for future reference.

Pay attention to the timestamps though and compare them with the actual real times you know, because some of the "late" messages like `systemd[1]: Started Suspend.` can be triggered right before the system actually turns off, but will actually be logged and written to disk with the timestamp of when it turns on again.

Comment: You were absolutely right about `dmesg`. Indeed, it does not keep count of how much time the system has been suspended for. That makes my answer not appropriate for what the OP wants to do, that's why I deleted it. Your answer, despite being the only one, seems to be the best for the job. Just one note: perhaps you could update your answer to only show the last suspend/resume event, since that's what the OP asked for. Thanks again for pointing out the `dmesg` limitation.

Comment: @user3140225 Thanks, I added some notes about that. Sorry that the effort you put into writing the script for your answer seemingly was in vain.

Comment: No worries. I learned something in the process: never trust `dmesg` timestamps!

Comment: Another problem in the dmesg based solution is that atleast in Ubuntu 16 dmesg default settings are such that event is cleared / not found after few ours.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16 it seems that "PM: suspend" and "PM: resume" events both are written into syslog during resume. So the suspend time in your solution is incorrectly same as the resume time. However, the resume time is correct.

Comment: @user4955663 Weird, on my system (also 16.04) I always have `PM: suspend entry` before sleeping and `PM: suspend exit` after waking up again in my syslog, with correct times, as you see in the example. Like I mentioned in the last paragraph of my answer, I only get e.g. `systemd[1]: Started Suspend` *after* it resumed. Maybe it's hardware-dependent somehow and your machine enters sleep mode more quickly? I also never saw a `PM: resume` message on mine. Is that after hibernation, or are you talking about sleep mode/suspension too?

Comment: PM: resume message comes after suspend operation, I cannot hibernate this machine.

Comment: maybe it will help somebody: I've noted I have `suspend entry (deep)` in syslog (`journalctl`) with timestamp of only after resume, but previous entries, e.g. `Starting Suspend` and `Suspending system` were with timestamp of much earlier, apparently before suspend. So one can grep for those (or both with `journalctl | grep -i suspend`).

Comment: On my laptop I sometimes notice similar to noted by @user4955663, so I post this answer as many I guess do not look in long comments sections. Below extends on Byte Commander answer: I've noted sometimes I have `suspend entry (deep)` in syslog (via `journalctl`) with timestamp of only after resume, but previous entries, e.g. `Starting Suspend` and `Suspending system` were with timestamp of much earlier, apparently before suspend. So one can grep for those (or both with `journalctl | grep -i suspend`). (`PM: suspend exit` for exit).